# $http get request returning html elements instead of database records in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

My get request's data array doesn't have database records; instead it contains the index.html's coding? How to rectify it?

Angular js Code initiating get request.

```js
$scope.displayEvent = function(){
    
           data = {}; $scope.events = {};
           console.log('Data before get request', data);
         $http.get('/api/events/display').success(function(data) {
//          
//             console.log( $scope.formData ); 
             console.log("Success: "+JSON.stringify(data));
             $scope.events = data;              
            
         }) .error(function(data){
             
         });
               
       };
```

```html
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createEvent()">Submit</button>    
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="displayEvent()">Display</button>
     
    </form>
        <br>
        
        <form>

            
        <div class="form-group">                         
            <ul ng-repeat="event in events ">
            
            <li>{{event.eventtitle}}</li>
<!--            <li><iframe ng-src= "{{imageUrl}}" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen imageChGallery=""></iframe> </li>-->
            </ul>
            
            </div>
```

Comment: if you use the exact same url in browser, what do you get?

Comment: seems like your api is returning HTML instead of json

Comment: Check in debugger/network what's sent from the server. It's probably HTML (so backend problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.displayEvent = function(){

       data = {}; $scope.events = {};
       console.log('Data before get request', data);
        $http.get('/api/events/display').success(function(response) {  

 console.log("Success: "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
             $scope.events = data;              

     }) .error(function(data){

     });

   };
```